# Laravel route articles.store not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a ArticleController but the store method is not defined.
Every other method shows up in route:list.
I have tried to delete the controller and made i again but no diffrence.
I made another controller and called it TestController and that worked fine.
Can someone help me with this?

**resources/views/create.blade.php**

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('articles.store') }}">
```

**app/http/Controllers/ArticleController.php**

```php
public function create()
{
    return view('staff.articles.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
  //Some code here
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::group(['prefix'=>'staff','middleware'=>['role:editor|author']],function()
{
  Route::resource('/articles','ArticleController');
});
```

**`php artisan route:list`**

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | staff/articles                      | articles.index      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index                           | web,role:editor|author |
|        | GET|HEAD  | staff/articles/create               | articles.create     | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@create                          | web,role:editor|author |
|        | DELETE    | staff/articles/{article}            | articles.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@destroy                         | web,role:editor|author |
|        | GET|HEAD  | staff/articles/{article}            | articles.show       | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@show                            | web,role:editor|author |
|        | PUT|PATCH | staff/articles/{article}            | articles.update     | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@update                          | web,role:editor|author |
|        | GET|HEAD  | staff/articles/{article}/edit       | articles.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@edit                            | web,role:editor|author |
```

Comment: If you post to /articles instead of using the named route, does it work? Your resource controller should handle the routes required for the full CRUD operation of your routes and controller.

Comment: Hmm, odd. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers indicates `Route::resource` should have created a `articles.store` `POST` route at `staff/articles`. Does `php artisan route:clear` work?

Comment: @eResourcesInc I don't think that'd work neither. It isn't listed when doing `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @Blue try adding the route manually: `Route::post('/articles', 'ArticleController@store');`

Comment: @HCK While that'll probably do the trick, `Route::resource` not doing it correctly indicates a problem of some sort that may have other impacts, and should be fixed.

Comment: Wonder if it has to do with the route group wrapping the resource controller? If you remove the resource controller for the Route::group, do you get the same route list?

Comment: @ceejayoz of course. Just said that to discart if there isn't an issue somewhere else.

Comment: @eResourcesInc's idea is a good one. I'd also check that you don't have another `POST` route in the full route list that's overriding `staff/articles`.

Comment: It's working now. I had another route in web.php which was causing problems.

Comment: @Blue show your middleware as well